# Making Page Divisions Clickable to Move

Tags: html, css

I have a couple partially stacked divisions that I need to make clickable with the mouse, and then when clicked, I need that division to move to the top of the stack. I am unsure of how to do this. No Javascript please. Thanks!

Edit: If JavaScript is the only possible way, how would you do that? Thanks!

Here is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.Start {background-color:green; 
width:300px;
height:300px;
position:relative;
}
.Middle {background-color:black; 
width:300px;
height:300px;
position:relative;
top:100px;
left:100px;
z-index=1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Start"></div>
<div class="Middle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that standard HTML pages are static meaning all the code within the HTML file determines the structure/content of the website. Each time that page is loaded the structure/content will be the same.

You will need JavaScript as it is the only language available for having your website communicate with the browser and watch for events such as clicks, mouse movements, key presses, etc and the list goes on. If you need access to those events, you are in JavaScript territory.

Comment: How would you do that with JavaScript?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://codepen.io/lachiekimber/pen/jvvvmZ - try to match it with your code to suit your needs. It's a basic click element to move to top.